# Execute Command Linux in PHP

Tags: php, linux, scrapy

How to execute linux command in php?

EDIT: this command is not output the result, this command is saving the scraped data into json file and display it using php, html

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['button']))
    {
         exec('(cd /var/www/html && scrapy crawl quotes -o - > /var/www/html/items.json -t json)');
    }
?>
```

Comment: try :  remove () of command

Comment: @pAsh tested, not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php system("cd /var/www/html && scrapy crawl quotes -o - > /var/www/html/items.json -t json", $retval); echo $retval; ?>
```

or you can put your command in backticks

```
<?php
  $output = `cd /var/www/html && scrapy crawl quotes -o - > /var/www/html/items.json -t json`;
 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: i don't need to output the result, what i want is saving the scraped data into json file and display it using php, html

Comment: <?php system("cd /var/www/html && scrapy crawl quotes -o - > /var/www/html/items.json -t json"); ?>

Comment: I have used PHPSeclib with symfony and successfully run SSH command like this: `$dir = $sftp->exec('cd applications/wnxnxrbpgf/public_html/phpsec; ls -la');` But first I have authenticated my sftp credentials.